# Implement simple authentication in Java servlet with tomcat server

Tags: java, session, authentication, servlets, token

Following the examples [here](https://youtu.be/4ouOAwoWIHg?t=112) and [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javaservlets.html), how I can implement simple authentication for Java servlet? The servlet is invoked via a URL which can be invoked from inside or outside the business network.

If the user is calling the url from inside the business network, then if the browser is running from an authenticated user account, or a valid network user, then the servlet should run.

If the user is calling the URL from outside the business network, then the user account must first perform authentication using forms based authentication (username/password), get a valid session ID as an authentication token, and use this token to pass it as a query parameter with the url. The token is simple a number or code that is passed as name/value pair. The servlet should check if the passed token is a valid session on the network, and it should allow or deny the request accordingly.

So basically, it's a two step process: first make sure the user calling the URL has a valid session on the network, if not, prompt him to authenticate. This step is outside the scope of this post. Let's assume that step one is done. Now, in step two, to call the servlet URL, the servlet will check if there is a valid authenticated session, if not, check if there is a session ID (token) passed in the url, and validate the session. If not, deny the request.

Below is a sample Java servlet which needs the above authentication mechanism:

```
package mypkg;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Set the response message's MIME type
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      // Write the response message, in an HTML page
      try {
         out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         out.println("<html><head>");
         out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
         out.println("<title>Hello, World</title></head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");  // says Hello
         // Echo client's request information
         out.println("<p>Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Protocol: " + request.getProtocol() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>PathInfo: " + request.getPathInfo() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Remote Address: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</p>");
         // Generate a random number upon each request
         out.println("<p>A Random Number: <strong>" + Math.random() + "</strong></p>");
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  // Always close the output writer
      }
   }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <!-- To save as <CATALINA_HOME>\webapps\helloservlet\WEB-INF\web.xml -->

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>mypkg.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <!-- Note: All <servlet> elements MUST be grouped together and
         placed IN FRONT of the <servlet-mapping> elements -->

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I used to perform such authentication using ASP.NET, but I am relatively new to Java, and I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: By the way, you can more conveniently annotate your Servlet as [shown here](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/quick-start-guide-for-java-servlet-annotations) in place of a `web.xml` file.